# Publish Typescript NPM Package -> Module Not Found When Consumed

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, npm-publish

I have a typescript project in which I am trying to import a self published typescript project. The imported project installs fine and I can see it's files and folders in node_modules in the consuming project. The modules of the imported project import correctly into my consuming typescript files. However, running my server I immediately get an error :

`Error: Cannot find module <correct path to module typescript file.`

I think it has something to do with my `tsconfig.json` or `package.json` so I have included their current setup. If it could be something else and I need to include it please give me a shout.

### Published Package

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "Some Name",
  "version": "1.0.3",
  "description": "Some Description",
  "types": "dist/src/types",
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint \"**/*.ts\" --quiet --fix"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "Some URL"
  },
  "author": "Richard Herbert",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "check-types": "^11.1.2",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sequelize": "^6.9.0",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.1",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/check-types": "^7.3.3",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "target": "es2017",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "paths": {
        "*": [
          "node_modules/*",
          "src/types/*"
        ]
      },
      "typeRoots": [
        "src/types",
        "node_modules/@types"
      ]
    },
    "include": [
      "src",
      "languages"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "**/__tests__/*"
    ]
  }
```

### Consuming Project

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "Some Name",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "description": "Some Description",
  "dependencies": {
    "@<scope/published-project>": "file:<Path To Published Package>",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.14.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.14.1",
    "ajv": "^8.6.1",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.926.0",
    "base58-random": "^0.1.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "check-types": "^11.1.2",
    "cli-progress": "^3.9.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "csv-generate": "^3.4.3",
    "csv-parse": "^4.16.0",
    "csv-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-rate-limit": "^5.4.1",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "helmet": "^4.4.1",
    "http-status-codes": "^2.1.4",
    "i18n": "^0.13.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mariadb": "^2.5.5",
    "minimist": "^1.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "mysqldump": "^3.2.0",
    "node-schedule": "^2.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "sequelize": "6.4.0",
    "sequelize-typescript": "2.0.0",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2",
    "stream-transform": "^2.1.3",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.0.2",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3",
    "winston": "^3.3.3",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.5.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/ajv": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/aws-sdk": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/bluebird": "^3.5.33",
    "@types/check-types": "^7.3.2",
    "@types/cli-progress": "^3.9.1",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.9",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/express-rate-limit": "^5.1.3",
    "@types/express-winston": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/i18n": "^0.13.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.4",
    "@types/minimist": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.22",
    "@types/node-schedule": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "@types/swagger-jsdoc": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.1",
    "@types/validator": "^13.1.3",
    "@types/winston": "^2.4.4",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint \"**/*.ts\" --quiet --fix",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev nodemon dist/<Project Folder>/src/api.js",
    "sync-db-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev node dist/src/scripts/sync-db.js",
    "sync-db-dev-new": "cross-env NODE_ENV=dev node dist/src/scripts/sync-db.js -f true -d true",
    "live": "nodemon dist/src/api.js"
  },
  "author": "Richard Herbert",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "module": "commonjs",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "target": "es2017",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "dist/",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "paths": {
        "*": [
          "node_modules/*",
          "src/types/*"
        ]
      },
      "typeRoots": [
        "src/types",
        "node_modules/@types"
      ]
    },
    "include": [
      "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
  
    ]
  }
```

Comment: How are you bundling your published package before publishing it?  Are you compiling it to JS first, or are you trying to just publish as .ts files.  If the latter is the case, you're gonna have a bad time

Comment: I am currently publishing as ts files. A bundler like webpack will solve my problem?